# ¿Por qué no se muestra el contenido real de la BD SQLite?

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, android-sqlite

Tengo creada una base de datos, si pulso en cualquiera de los elementos que contiene la base de datos, me muestra sin problemas la información de ese elemento.

```
private static final String TABLA_NOTAS =
    "CREATE TABLE contactos " +
            "(_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            " nombre VARCHAR(100), direccion VARCHAR(100)," +
            " movil VARCHAR(100), movil_2 VARCHAR(100)," +
            " fijo VARCHAR(100), fijo_2 VARCHAR(100)," +
            " fax VARCHAR(100), fax_2 VARCHAR(100)," +
            " grupo VARCHAR(100), puesto VARCHAR(100)," +
            " mail VARCHAR(100), mail_2 VARCHAR(100));";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo que me esta dando problemas, no mostrando la información correcta es en lo siguiente....

En el campo **grupo** introduzco los diferentes grupos (ahora solo tengo dos, Grupo 1 y Grupo 2) para poder mostrar un listado con un grupo determinado.

Por ejemplo, quiero mostrar todas las fichas ordenadas que están en el Grupo 1.

Las muestra bien, estas tres son las que campo grupo contiene el texto Grupo 1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema viene a la hora de mostrar la información, por ejemplo del segundo elemento, que no muestra la información de su ficha, si no que muestra la que estaba en su momento en el primer listado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que tengo para que muestre los que están en el Grupo 1:

```
// Ordena por Grupo
public Cursor recuperaContactosGrupo_1() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    String[] valores_recuperar = {"_id", "nombre", "direccion", "movil", "movil_2", "fijo", "fijo_2", "mail", "mail_2", "fax", "fax_2", "grupo", "estacion" };

    String[] args = new String[] {"Grupo 1"};

    Cursor c = db.query("contactos", valores_recuperar, "grupo=?", args, null, null, "nombre ASC",null);

    return c;

}


// Si pulsamos el un item de la Lista, 
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View view, int posicion, long id) {
    iDAct= ids[posicion];
    muestraDatosenBtSh();
}


// Funcion para ordenar los contactos del Grupo 1
public void ordenaPorGrupo_1(View v){
    adaptador = new Adaptador(this, bdAgenda.recuperaContactosGrupo_1());
    setListAdapter(adaptador);
    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
    setSnackBar(mLayout,getString(R.string.tablaorden3));
```

Aqui muestro la ficha, donde oculto un FloatingActionButton y muestro una serie botones para hacer una llamada.

```
// Abre el Lay del BotomSheet con los datos del usuario
private void muestraDatosenBtSh(){

    final Contacto contacto;

    bSB.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);

    contacto= bdAgenda.recuperarContacto(iDAct);

    btsheet_image_foto.setImageBitmap(recogerImagen(contacto.getNombre()+".png"));
    btsheet_nombre.setText(contacto.getNombre());
    btsheet_movil.setText(contacto.getMovil());
    btsheet_movil_2.setText(contacto.getMovil_2());
    btsheet_fijo.setText(contacto.getFijo());
    btsheet_fijo_2.setText(contacto.getFijo_2());

    bSB.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

         @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                fab.hide();
            }
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                fab.show();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {}

    });

    // Cierra el btsheep cuando pulsamos el boton
    btsheet_low.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            bSB.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        }
    });

    // Codigo que abre el telefono para llamar al contacto
       ....
       ....
       ....
       ....
       ....
}
```

¿Porque cuando pulso en una de las ficha no me muestra la información de esa ficha?

Un saludo.

Comment: y el codigo de lo que muestra una ficha?

Comment: Hola  @gbianchi ya he puesto el código en el primer post, con las pruebas que estoy haciendo espero que este correcto, al no recibir notificaciones por correo, he seguido intento buscar el problema.

Comment: Estas pasando la posicion del objeto en la lista, en lugar del ID del objeto, ese es el problema. No tengo ni idea donde esta guardado ese ID...

Comment: Te iba a decir que acabo de poner la Función para ordenar los contactos del Grupo 1, y he visto tu respuesta, ese ID también se guarda en la base de datos, pero los valores que recupera al realizar la búsqueda, a parte del campo "grupo" no recupera también el ID ? , si no es así, como se recupera el ID de ese objeto?

Comment: Tenes que recuperar el ID, y luego buscar por ID. Tu aplicacion esta funcionando de casualidad.

Comment: Podría poner alguien un código de ejemplo para ver como poder hace lo que comenta gbianchi ? que por mas que intento buscar una solución no lo consigo.